# How do I change the DataTemplate while adding a new row to a DataGrid (for the new row only)

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I need to show a DataGrid of that hides some sensitive information until the user actively requests it.  I've construct the columns thus:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="User Name" Binding="{Binding UserName}" IsReadOnly="False" MinWidth="90"/>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Password" IsReadOnly="False" MinWidth="90">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="Show"                                              
        Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ShowPassword, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Owner Only" Binding="{Binding OwnerOnly}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsOwner, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}" MinWidth="90"/>
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Active" Binding="{Binding Active}" IsReadOnly="False" MinWidth="90"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Created" Binding="{Binding Created, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm\}}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="90"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Superseded" Binding="{Binding Superseded, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm\}}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="90"/>
```

Which produces this:

[image]

When the user clicks on the Show button they are shown another view which audits the access and allows them to change the password.

The only problem I have is that I want to allow them to add new rows.  When they do so they can't specify the password because that column is a button not a text field.

Question: is there anyway of changing that button on the 'new row' to be a TextBox?

Environment: MVVM with nothing in the code behind files.  I don't mind putting some stuff in the code behind if that's the only way.

Thanks

## SOLUTION

The accepted answer gave me 90 % of what I needed but I had to add a second data trigger...

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <Button x:Key="btn" Content="Show"                                              
Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ShowPassword, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource btn}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Password}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Content">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TextBox />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" Value="{x:Static CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder}">
                        <Setter Property="Content">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TextBox />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: you could have a button and a textBox inside that datatemplate. and you can then bind visibility of both: button visible when its an old entry, textbox visible when its a new entry

Comment: You've probably moved on from this but I just saw this and I'm super curious to know: why didn't you simply use the `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate` for the edit mode textbox instead of taking the long convoluted route of triggers?

Comment: Clicking on Show opens another View (which audits who read the password and for what reason) it doesn't just allow the user to edit in the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `ContentControl` that binds to the parent `DataContext` and displays a `TextBox` if it is a `NewItemPlaceholder`. Something like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Password" IsReadOnly="False" MinWidth="90">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl>
                <ContentControl.Resources>
                    <Button x:Key="btn" Content="Show"                                              
                                        Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ShowPassword, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                </ContentControl.Resources>
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource btn}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" Value="{x:Static CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder}">
                                <Setter Property="Content">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <TextBox />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Looks promising, but I'm off till the New Year now - I'll try it as soon as I'm back and mark as answer if it works.  Thanks.

Comment: As soon as I start typing in the first column the TextBox reverts to the button. The new row immediately looses its NewItemPlaceholder (and the ctor for the target class gets invoked at that point so I guess the row is changing from a dummy place holder to a place holder to the new object). So... I added a second trigger checking for null passwords and this makes it look right.  I've added the XAML I'm currently using to my question.  Thanks.